# Securing JMXConnectorServerService (jmx-remoting.sar) in JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Tags: security, jboss, jmx, jboss5.x

I've been trying to understand how to secure the JMXConnectorServerService offered by JBoss 5.1.0.GA by default.

Currently, if I paste the following URL into JConsole, I can get to JMX directly without any authentication: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:1290/jmxconnector

Then I did this to secure my JMXInvoker in hopes that that would secure all JMX access: http://objectopia.com/2009/10/01/securing-jmx-invoker-layer-in-jboss/

But, apparently, that doesn't apply to the JMXConnectorServerService. I can still get to JMX using the the above service URL through jconsole.

Then I found out about this feature request that hasn't been accommodated yet: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8159

Now, presently I'm not worried about crazy security measures. This URL is not gonna be exposed to the outside network. So, I just want to see what's the simplest way for me to secure the jmx-remoting.sar with the "jmx-console" security domain?

I could switch to the default MBean server, but apparently, in 5.1.0.GA, that's a pain: https://community.jboss.org/thread/153594

I'd really appreciate any input in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: Another interesting article that's relevant: http://labs.consol.de/blog/jmx4perl/jboss-remote-jmx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that service has been secured, but there is a [patch](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/attachmentzip/unzip/12414094/12335900%5B6%5D/org/jboss/mx/remoting/service/JMXConnectorServerService.java).

For a slightly simpler version, I am going out on a limb here, since I have not tested this on AS 5, but I backported it to AS 4 and it worked ok.

I'm not sure which version you have, exactly, but let's assume it is [this one](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jboss/mx/remoting/service/JMXConnectorServerService.java.html). The EAP version has a slightly more involved version, but the premise is the same. You will need to extend [JMXConnectorServerService](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jboss/mx/remoting/service/JMXConnectorServerService.java.html) and [JMXConnectorServerServiceMBean](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jboss/mx/remoting/service/JMXConnectorServerServiceMBean.java.html).

In this implementation, the code to create the server looks like this:

```
// create new connector server and start it
connectorServer = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, null, mbeanServer);
```

In your extension, add the following:

```
/** The name of the JAAS domain to use for authentication */
protected String jaasDomain = null; 
...
/**
   * Returns the name of the JAAS domain to use for authentication
   * @return the name of a JAAS Domain
   */
public String getJaasDomain() {
   return jaasDomain;
}

/**
  * Sets the name of the JAAS domain to use for authentication
  * @param jaasDomain the JAAS Domain to use for authentication
  */
public void setJaasDomain(String jaasDomain) {
   this.jaasDomain = jaasDomain;
}
```

Now you need to reimplement the **start** method which adds an environment containing the JAAS domain name you want to authenticate with.

```
   public void start() throws Exception
   {
      // the address to expose in the urls
      String host = System.getProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname");

      // check to see if registry already created
      rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, registryPort);
      if (rmiRegistry != null)
      {
         try
         {
            rmiRegistry.list();
         }
         catch(RemoteException e)
         {
            log.debug("No registry running at host '" + host +
                  "', port '" + registryPort + "'.  Will create one.");
            rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(registryPort, null, new DefaultSocketFactory(bindAddress));
         }
      }
      else
      {
         rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(registryPort, null, new DefaultSocketFactory(bindAddress));
      }

      String serviceURL = "service:jmx:rmi://" + host + "/jndi/rmi://" + host + ":" + registryPort + jndiPath;

      JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(serviceURL);

      // create new connector server and start it
      // ==== NEW AUTH CODE HERE ====
      final Map<String, Object> environment = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      environment.put("jmx.remote.x.login.config", jaasDomain);
      connectorServer = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, environment, mbeanServer);
      // ==== NEW AUTH CODE ENDS ====
      connectorServer.start();

      log.info("JMX Connector server: " + serviceURL);
   }
```

You can optionally validate the JAAS name like this:

```
/**
 * Validates the name of the passed JAAS domain. 
 * If the name is not valid, a RuntimeException will the thrown.
 * @param domain The name of the JAAS domain to validate.
 */
private void validateJaasDomain(String domain) {
    try {
        new LoginContext(domain);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("The JAAS Domain [" + domain + "] could not be loaded", e);
    }
}
```

Add the jaasDomain attribute to the new MBean interface:

```
/**
 * Returns the name of the JAAS domain to use for authentication
 * @return the name of a JAAS Domain
 */
public String getJaasDomain();

/**
 * Sets the name of the JAAS domain to use for authentication
 * @param jaasDomain the JAAS Domain to use for authentication
 */
public void setJaasDomain(String jaasDomain);
```

Let's assume your new impl is **com.vijay.JMXConnectorServerService** and the new MBean is **com.vijay.JMXConnectorServerServiceMBean**; You deployment descriptor would look like this:  (using the *jmx-console* jaas domain, since you probably have that secured....)

```
<!-- ======================================================== -->
<!-- Example Vijay JMX Remoting Service Configuration file        -->
<!-- ======================================================== -->
<server>

   <mbean code="com.vijay.JMXConnectorServerService"
      name="jboss.remoting:service=JMXConnectorServer,protocol=rmi"
      display-name="JMX Connector Server (RMI)">
           <attribute name="BindAddress">
               <!-- Get the port from the ServiceBindingManager -->
               <value-factory bean="ServiceBindingManager" method="getStringBinding" 
                  parameter="jboss.remoting:service=JMXConnectorServer,protocol=rmi"/>
            </attribute>
            <!-- if comment this out, will use 1099 as default and will conflict -->
            <!-- with default JNP (JNDI) port. -->
            <attribute name="RegistryPort">
               <!-- Get the port from the ServiceBindingManager -->
               <value-factory bean="ServiceBindingManager" method="getIntBinding" 
                  parameter="jboss.remoting:service=JMXConnectorServer,protocol=rmi"/>
            </attribute>
            <!-- the path to which will be bound in rmi registry -->
            <!-- the commented value below is the default. -->
            <!-- <attribute name="JndiPath">/jmxconnector</attribute> -->
            <attribute name="JaasDomain">jmx-console</attribute>
   </mbean>
</server>
```

That's all I have. I hope it is useful to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a comprehensive answer. I really wish I could vote multiple times for this one, but unfortunately I get only one. :(

This has been very helpful and useful.

Unfortunately, for now, I'm just gonna rely on a firewall rule that allows access to the port only to my monitoring server.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried using the validation method with a modified version of JB 5.1.0GA used by Mobicents but it fails saying the security domain is not available. It may be due to the fact that the domain is not yet available when the service is started because if I disable the validation everything works fine, but I haven't had the time to investigate. Either way, thanks.

Comment: @Morfic; You might be able to get around this by adding a dependency on one of the security MBeans, such as jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager. Perhaps the domain will be available one this MBean completes its startup.